# Do all homology 3-spheres bound some contractible 4-manifold

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

I read in several places that "Every $Y^3$ with the integral homology of $S^3$ bounds a contractible $4$-manifold $\Delta^4$".

But in Kervaire's paper "Smooth homology spheres and their fundamental groups" it was written "The following well-known construction provides an example of a 3-dimensional homology sphere which does not bound a contractible manifold."

What did I miss? 
If it was a suitable for MO, I will move it to SE.

Comment: It only works in the topological category, and is due to Freedman.  It doesn't work in PL or smooth category, for example the Poincare homology sphere does not bound a contractible 4-manifold with PL structure, because the signature is 8 rather than divisible by 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Poincare homology sphere(with negative orientation)  bounds a smooth contractible 4 manifold then cap it off with an $-E_8$ plumbing will give you a simplyconnected 4 manifold with $-E_8$ intersection form [It's a -ve definite 4 manifold]. The famous theorem of Donaldson says that if a closed , simplyconnected 4 manfold is -ve definite then the intersection form has to be diagonilazable. Although $E_8$ is not diagonalizable. So contradiction.

Although Freedman's famous result says every homology sphere embedded inside $S^4$ in a topological sense. That means it bounds a contractible 4 manifold in topological category.